# Keep images original size using changeImage

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-resizing

I have thumbnails sitting next to a larger image, when you click the thumbnails its changes the larger image to which ever thumbnail is clicked but is is taking on the size of the thumbnail instead of keeping it's original size, is there a way to stop the image resizing when it changes?

The code I am using is:

```
function changeImage(x){
    document.getElementById('image').src = x.src;
}

<img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" onclick="changeImage(this)" />
```

For a preview of it working, look here: http://nthwondr.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=59&product_id=61

I cannot use a set height width as the picture will be different sizes on different devices.

Thanks guys.

Comment: do you mean, [aspect ratio] ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and height of the big image by retrieving the width and height of the clicked thumbnail an multiplying those values say by 2 or 3 after changing big image's source.

**Edit**

```
//this will get the properties of the passed element
function getElProps(el,attr){

//checking if the browser is Internet Explorer    
isIEX = navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/);

whaT_ = isIEX ? el.currentStyle : window.getComputedStyle(el);

getWhaT_ =  isIEX ? whaT_.getAttribute(attr) : whaT_.getPropertyValue(attr);

    return getWhaT_;

}

function changeImage(x){
    document.getElementById('image').src = x.src;
    height_ = getElProps(x,'height');
    width_ = getElProps(x,'width');
    document.getElementById('image').style.height = parseInt(height_)*3 + 'px';
    document.getElementById('image').style.width = parseInt(width_)*3 + 'px';
}

<img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" onclick="changeImage(this)" />
```

Comment: This may work, I will have to have a look, can you tell me how I can integrate that into my code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 `data` attributes for example

```
<img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" data-high-res="<?php echo $image['high-res']; ?>" />
```

the attribute `data-high-res` will have the high resolution image of the thumb and use jQuery instead

```
  $('img').click(function () {
        var $element = $(this),
            $highResImg = $element.data('high-res');
        $('#imgHighRes').attr('src', $highResImg);
    });
```

And the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAzad/HrKqh/) should explain more

Comment: Hi Adam, this is what I need, I found out that there is a high res version of the images so I have added in your code but it is not working:
`$('img').click(function () {
    var $element = $(this),
        $highResImg = $element.data('popup');
    $('#image').attr('src', $highResImg);
});`

Original image:
`<img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image" />`

Comment: Thumbnail:
`<img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" data-high-res="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" onclick="changeImage(this)" />`

Comment: When I click the thumbnail I get the following errors:

`event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard.prevenrDefault() instead.`

`Uncaught ReferenceError: changeImage is not defined.`

Comment: I took out the `onclick` attribute and added `id="img"` to the thumbnail, now I only get the first error when I click.